# How to pass data from parent component to child component in vue composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

i am developing an example to learn how to use `props` as shown in this url :https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow
as shown in the code below, in App.vue,  i receive an error when i try to use

> `<HelloWorld :name=refName/>`

I revised some posts about this issue but still I could not figure out why I am receiving it.
So, my questions are:

1. How to pass value to `:name` from `App.vue`
2. I read about `props vs data`, how to define data in the the parent class `App.vue` with composition API

**App**

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld :name=refName/>  <!-- ERROR: unexpected end of 
expression-->
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { onBeforeMount,onMounted,onUpdated,onBeforeUpdate,onActivated,onDeactivated,onBeforeUnmount,onUnmounted, ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(['name_'])
const refName = ref(props.name_)
refName = "test"

</script>
```

**helloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
  <h1>{{ props.name }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  // props: {
  //   msg: String
  // }
}
</script>

<script setup>
import { onBeforeMount,onMounted,onUpdated,onBeforeUpdate,onActivated,onDeactivated,onBeforeUnmount,onUnmounted } from 'vue'
import { defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(['name','address','phone'])

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refName` must have been enclosed between qoutes

`<HelloWorld :name="refName"/>`